# Puppet master (3.6.2) error on signing puppet client (2.7.25)

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I was hoping someone might have an answer for this:

While upgrading overall from Centos6 to Centos7 I'm handling the upgrade for puppet's version. Our new puppet server's version is `3.6.2` and I'd like it to work with the somewhat older puppet clients whose version is `2.7.25`.

This is the problem I'm running into:

puppet cert --list --all

```
+"XXX.YYY.com"   (MD5) 7C:0D:73:12:D6:53:62:94:12:DF:0F:1E:4E:DC:C5:34

+"puppet.polldev.com"    (SHA256) 74:8D:84:3F:B4:FC:F6:5A:12:22:B0:63:2A:44:15:93:FB:47:E2:70:AA:F7:AF:B4:E8:62:D8:84:3B:CC:77:10
```

Then when I try to sign:

```
puppet cert sign XXX.YYY.com
```

> Warning: Sections other than main, master, agent, user are deprecated in puppet.conf. Please use the directory environments feature to specify environments. (See http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/environments.html)
>      (at /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/settings/config_file.rb:77:in `collect')
>
> Error: unknown message digest algorithm

Are there any workarounds or solutions for this which don't involve setting up an external CA or using `3.x` clients as well?

Thanks, I'd appreciate any help on this if anyone has any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. You have to update your puppet clients:

https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-3176

Comment: A workaround I found in the mean time (which at least lets me sign the certificates without having to upgrade the clients) is this:

sed -i -e 's/csr.sign(key, OpenSSL::Digest::MD5.new)/csr.sign(key,  OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new)/'  /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/ssl/certificate_request.rb

It's ugly but since at the moment I can't afford to upgrade the clients it might be a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

These are two unrelated issues.

1. The first warning is about Directory Environments, which are the replacement of the old dynamic environments. See the mentioned URL.
2. The Error is the real problem. I think a Puppet agent that old will be using MD5 as a message digest, which new servers will not accept due to FIPS compliancy. You need to update your clients to something that supports at least SHA-1 or SHA-256. Version 2.7 is EOL (see thread at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/puppet-users/8JEy7wY5VPs/9N07fgfU1mAJ)

You may also want to ask the [Puppet-Users mailing-list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/puppet-users). There are some smart people on there that may be able to provide a workaround for upgrading your agents. 2.7 is pretty old though, so any workaround should a be temporary one while you upgrade your agents.